# Is there any way to copy address of every array's element address to another pointer array without using loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, embedded

I am currently making a kind of 'controller' variable that can change the original variable's value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changearr(int* arr[]);

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[3] = {3,4,5}; 
    int* controller[3]; 
    int idx = 0; 
    printf("Value of array is : "); 
    for (idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) 
    { 
        printf(" %d", arr[idx]); 
        controller[idx] = &arr[idx]; 
    } 
    printf("\n");

    changearr(controller); // arr is now changed by the controller value
    
    printf("Value of array is :");
    for (idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        printf(" %d", arr[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;

}

void changearr(int* arr[]) 
{ 
    int idx = 0; 
    for (idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) 
    { 
        *arr[idx] += 1; 
    } 
}
```

Code seems to work as I expected.

However, I don't like the part that variable 'controller'(which is a pointer array) should be initialized under for loop.

Is there any way like 'memcpy' to make the code simpler?

Comment: Tip: Put your `int` declaration inside your `for` as in `for (int idx = 0; ...)` as this keeps the declaration both obvious and hard to forget.

Comment: @Armandas I am currently using C, but it would be helpful if you inform me of any other methods used in other languages

Comment: Tip: Instead of forward declaring functions, just move their definition to before where they're used the first time. This is how a lot of C code tends to be structured anyway, so programmers are familiar with, for example, things building up to `main()`, not that being the first thing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer oops sorry, i will edit the tag

Comment: Please do not ask for "other methods used in other languages" because that advice will be completely useless for you. Are you going to use `std::vector` in C? Probably not.

Comment: @PepijnKramer You got a point. But, the example shown above is just the part of  what i am going to do. What I am originally going to do is that making structure variables that may share common address of other variables. I will eidt the question by adding the extra explanation & example

Comment: Your first array is integers. The 'increment' between pointer values will likely be 4. Another person's array may be doubles (increment value = 8)... Another may have an array of struct's of some arbitrary size (and quantity.) No, neither the language nor the standard libraries try to be all things to all people. What is the use case you have in mind that requires the extra level of indirection?

Comment: @tadman I am currently building software for embedded C, so nope... thank you anyway

Comment: I can't see the need for 3 (or 4) pointers if each pointer is to point to adjacent elements of a contiguous array of integers. Probably simpler to just use one pointer (if needed) and offset from that as needed.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I get it! thanks :) Seems I made things too complicated

Comment: @tadman Concerning source code layout, this is most commonly fixed by the style guide that professionals use. And by my long experience the mostly used order is first prototypes, then main (top level function(s)), finally definitions, simply because it helps understanding the source from top to bottom. The other way around is much more difficult. However, this is opinionated. ;-)

Comment: @YHCho Would you mind to extend your use case to a [mre], please? For example, I don't see why you need an array of pointers, if a pointer to array (and an entry for its size) could suffice. -- Anyway, during runtime you cannot populate an array like you describe without a loop. During compile time, there _can_ be options.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for the advice. And now I realize that I try to did a something dumb after having a good night sleep and check my question again. (haha) As Fe2O3 said, it is perfectly fine to use one pointer and offset from it. The structure I've defined will be only valid when each element of the pointer array contains address of other pre-defined arrays. (And those pre-defined arrays doesn't share any address).

Comment: @thebusybee Also I simplified my question, following 'minimal reproducible example'.

Comment: Yeah, now it's much better, thanks! -- However, please do not place a solution _into_ the question. You can write an own answer showing your solution, and mark it (later, after some time), because that way the question will be more helpful for future visitors, including your future self. IIRC you can change the mark from the currently selected answer.

Comment: @thebusybee My question is edited following your advice, by adding my own answer. Thanks for being a good reviewer!

Comment: Rolled back to the version of the question to which the accepted answer applies.  If you have a question about significantly different code, post a new question.  You should not materially change the question when editing it, especially if a valid answer has already been given.  It renders the answer given in good faith nonsense, and is bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noted in the comments, `controller` serves no real purpose since you could pass `arr` and more simply index that `arr[idx]` where you currently have `*arr[idx]`.  It seems to be an unnecessary level of indirection.  In general though, there is no *runtime* non-iterative solution to generate an array of pointers to elements of an array (even if that made any kind of sense).  You can statically initialise the array of course:

```
    int arr[3] = {3,4,5}; 
    int* controller[3] = {&arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]} ;
```

But that would only be useful if the elements of `controller` were to be changed at runtime, (by sorting for example).